# How to return ViewModel PagedList [ASP MVC]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to return a category page with paging .... I got a problem with that in my view , I can't handle the View Model Members , and can't to control them ...

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class CategoryVm
{
    public List<Book> Book { set; get; }

    public Category Category_Content { get; set; }

    
}
```

Also here is the controller :

```
public ActionResult Category(int? id, int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = 6;
        int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
        if (id != null)
        {
            var vm = new CategoryVm();
            vm.Category_Content = db.Categories.Where(t => t.Category_id == id).Single();
            vm.Book = db.Books.Where(b => b.Category_id == id).ToList();
            if (vm != null)
            {
                //Here I have the problem , it telling me that 'CategoryVm' does not contain a definition for 'ToPagedList'
                return View(vm.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

            }
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("index",new { Controller = "Home" });
    }
```

and here is my view :

```
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model PagedList.IPagedList<SmartBookLibrary.ViewModel.CategoryVm>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Category_Content.Category_name+ " - Smart Books Library";
}

    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="lead">Categories</p>
            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Developers</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">

            

            <div class="row">
@foreach (var item in Model.Book)
{
                
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">

                    <figure class="snip1091 navy">
                        <img src="~/Images/@item.Book_Image" alt="sq-sample6" />
                        <figcaption>
                            <label>@item.Book_name</label>
                        </figcaption><a href="/Category/@item.Category.Category_id"></a>
                    </figure>


                    
                </div>
}


            </div>
            Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
            @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Category", new {page}))


        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I the view I can't access the model :

> ViewBag.Title = Model.**Category_Content**
>
> @foreach (var item in Model.**Book**)

so how to fix that , and make the paging work ??

Comment: `ToPagedList` needs to be applied to an `IEnumerable`. Your viewmodel is an boject that contains a property that is an `IEnumerable`

Comment: Thanks , so how to solve this sir ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your view model to use the Paged list

```
public class CategoryVm {
    public IPagedList<Book> Book { set; get; }

    public Category Category_Content { get; set; }
}
```

Then assign the paged list to your view model

```
public ActionResult Category(int? id, int? page) {
    int pageSize = 6;
    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    if (id != null) {
        var vm = new CategoryVm();
        vm.Category_Content = db.Categories.Where(t => t.Category_id == id).Single();
        var books = db.Books.Where(b => b.Category_id == id).ToList();
        if (vm != null) {
            //Apply paged list to view model.
            vm.Books = books.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
            return View(vm);
        }
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("index",new { Controller = "Home" });
}
```

Now in your view change the model.

```
@model SmartBookLibrary.ViewModel.CategoryVm
```

And

```
Page @(Model.Book.PageCount < Model.Book.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Book.PageNumber) of @Model.Book.PageCount
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Book, page => Url.Action("Category", new {page}))
```

Comment: If anybody runs into an error at `@Html.PagedListPager`, you just need to add `@using PagedList.Mvc` to the top of your view

Answer (score 1):

According to here ToPageList will be applied to IEnumerable or IQueryable:
https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList

```
        var vm = new CategoryVm();
        vm.Category_Content = db.Categories.Where(t => t.Category_id == id).Single();
        vm.Book = db.Books.Where(b => b.Category_id == id).ToList();
        if (vm != null)
        {
            var newListCategoryVm = new List<CategoryVm>() {vm}

            return View(newListCategoryVm.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

        }
```

In the view you know now that you need to for each or whatever you like.